# Nao microphones and google API in ROS

Tags: ros, audio, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to implement a speech detection which will send sentences to the google API and get the text. This will be permanently listening and doesn't need any vocabulary. so before starting I thought it would be better to ask maybe somebody already did something like that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151781/nao-microphones-and-google-api-in-ros/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-04-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bapclenet](https://answers.ros.org/users/11526/bapclenet/) on 2014-06-07**:
I'm looking for something like you, have you tried the package audio_common?
http://wiki.ros.org/audio_common
It should catch the sound from the microphones and publish an /audio message.
Let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A similar thing has been done here https://github.com/Barista-Bot/voice-control in python.

This wasn't on a Nao but our own proprietary robot.

Hope it may be of use.

---

Originally posted by [rmb209](https://answers.ros.org/users/14126/rmb209/) with karma: 80 on 2014-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a simpler library, you may want to check [gspeet](https://github.com/severin-lemaignan/gspeett): it's a small python library that listen (continously or not) on the microphone (using ALSA. It should work on Nao), encode the speech using the `speex` encoder (well, a google variant of it, actually -- it still requires `libspeex`), send it to Google speech API, and returns the result.

Integration in a ROS node should be trivial, but the library itself is independant.

---

Originally posted by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) with karma: 240 on 2014-05-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1